# vagrant run a chef cookbook

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

So I have Vagrant installed and running, in a directory I have some chef stuff. I notice when vagrant boots it runs all my chef recipes and cookbooks. But I am modifying behavior to and need to run chef while vagrant is running, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documentation says, you must use:

- [`vagrant provision`](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/provision.html) when you modify any cookbook
- [`vagrant reload`](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/reload.html) when you modify `Vagrantfile` - it is equivalent to `halt` + `up`

Answer (score 2):

Run in the command line:

```
vagrant provision
```